# Windows API function not available while it should be

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I'm trying to create a symbolic link using Windows's API, however the [`CreateSymbolicLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx) function doesn't seem to exist even though I've included `windows.h`.

I'm using Qt Creator. I am able to use other functions from the API except this one.

Can anyone explain why?

I'm on Windows 8.1.

**Edit:**

My code:

```
#include "windows.h"

bool createSymbolicLink(const int &type, const QString &linkPath, const QString &targetPath) {
    DWORD windows_Type = type;
    wchar_t* windows_LinkPath = new wchar_t[linkPath.length()];
    linkPath.toWCharArray(windows_LinkPath);
    wchar_t* windows_TargetPath = new wchar_t[targetPath.length()];
    targetPath.toWCharArray(windows_TargetPath);

    return CreateSymbolicLinkW(windows_LinkPath, windows_TargetPath, windows_Type) != 0;
}
```

The error: 'CreateSymbolicLinkW' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateSymbolicLink` has a minimum requirement of Vista, as [documented at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363866.aspx).

This means that you need to specify by way of a conditional define that you are targeting Vista and up. You can find more documentation here:

- [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).
- [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx).

So, you could include these defines before you include the windows header file.

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

If this does not help then you have out of date SDK and will need to switch to a more up to date SDK.

Comment: I'll look into that, but shouldn't the function show up regardless? Or do I have to have the conditional for it to appear?
EDIT:
I've included the defines but I'm still unable to use the function and the compiler throws an error.

Comment: If you don't define these conditionals, the functions are not declared. You have to opt in to higher Windows versions. Otherwise you can accidentally link to functions that are not available on the version of Windows that you target. For example, if you want your code to run on Windows XP, you would have to find a different approach. Runtime linking to the function, only if it is available. Otherwise, some fallback code for older Windows versions.

Comment: Oh wait, I cleaned the project and tried again and now it worked - However, now I'm receiving the following warnings:
"WINVER" redefined [enabled by default]

"_WIN32_WINNT" redefined [enabled by default]

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Qt, or how you've configured your project. I think I've set you on the way from the Win32 API side of things.